# Upload content:// file to server

Tags: php, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have uri of file on android phone : `content://com.android.contacts/contacts/472/photo`. I got it from PhoneGap [Contacts](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#Contacts) plugin. It is actually contact image. Now I need to upload that image on server but when I upload it and try to see it it is not visible. 
I managed to google a little bit and found that for file upload I need to have full `file://` path.
Now my question is how to convert `content://` to `file://` or how to upload files with `content://` uri on server?

I have tried using `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(uri, win, fail);` and than

```
function win(fe){
    alert("win");
    alert(fe.fullPath);
}
function fail(a){
    alert('fail');
}
```

But somehow it just "skipp" `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(uri, win, fail);`. It is never executed... No error in LogCat and no any alert from these 3 ... 
Can this be solution of my problem and why no response is returned?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have direct experience with the contacts plugin, but the docs make me think that you are not looking at a filesystem URI, rather an entry in the contacts database. 
[http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#contacts.find]

So, you are likely mis-interpreting the concept of a URI, especially in the context of the filesystem. [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier] and [http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/].

From the plugin docs, we do see that 'photos' is a property of each contact.

> > how to upload files with content:// uri on server?

for the desired contact, you could create a file using the photos property, and then upload  using the phonegap file-transfer plugin. [http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer]